# Django REST Framework : ListCreateAPI and RetrieveUpdateDelete Api for complex foreign key relationships

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Apologies if this seems trivial but i want to know what is the most Django way to do this. Below are the models, views and serializers listed for reference.

There are 3 models. I am just showing the relevant fields for each, though they have multiple fields. Now, one blog can have multiple authors contribute to it. Similarly one author or contributor can contribute to multiple blogs.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="120")
    ...

class Author(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="120")
    ...

class BlogAuthor(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog') 
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    # Should the above relations be a Foreign Key or ManyToMany Field
```

I am using DRF 3.0 to create the below APIs:

```
        GET /blogs/1/author : to get a list of authors for the blog identified by id 1
Sample Output: {
                 id: 1,
                 blog_id:1,
                 authors:[1,2,3] #or authors:{1,2,3}
               }
        POST /blogs/1/author: create which authors are related to the blog 1
        GET /blogs/1/author/1: show details of the author 1 in context of the blog 1; for ex, author 1 may have contributed 300 words to blog 1 so this would return that along with some other details, say name of the author, picture of the author etc
        DELETE /blogs/1/author/1 : deletes the relation between blog 1 and author 1, thought both entities exist; just the relationship between them is deleted
```

The relevant urls:

```
path('blogs/<int:blog_pk>/authors/', views.BlogAuthorList.as_view(), name='blogauthor-list'),
path('blogs/<int:blog_pk>/authors/<int:pk>', views.BlogAuthorList.as_view(), name='blogauthor-detail'),
```

I have also created the views and the serializers but i am not very sure.

```
Serializer:
class BlogAuthor(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        creator = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='creator.username')

        class Meta:
            model = BlogAuthor
            fields = ('id', 'blog', 'author', 'creator')

    View:
    class BlogAuthorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = BlogAuthor.objects.all() # notsure
        serializer_class = BlogAuthorSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

        #The below was working early but since i introduced the new URLs, see paths above am getting error as shown above
        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            public_personas = request.data.get('authors')
    #To handle multiple authors sent from API, ie, to handle requests such as #: 
   # {
   #     "blog": 1,
   #     "author": [1,3]
   # }
            data = {}
            response_data = []
            response_dict = {}
            for author in authors:
                data['blog'] = request.data.get('blog')
                data['author'] = author
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    self.perform_create(serializer)
                    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                    response_data.append(serializer.data)
                else:
                    return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            response_dict['data'] = response_data
            return Response(response_dict, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)

        # def list(self, request):
        #   Not Sure How To Do This


    #Not sure about this.
    class BlogAuthor(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
        ???
```

Thats quite a long question. Sorry about that. Do let me know your thoughts and point me in the right direction on how to do this. I feel this is quite a common occurence so should be straight forward but have scratched my head for quite some time now.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried this, `path('blogs/<int:blog_pk>/authors/<int:author_pk>', views.BlogAuthorList.as_view(), name='blogauthor-detail'),`

Comment: yes but to no avail. @JerinPeterGeorge

Comment: well i restarted everything and not atleast the create part is working however i am not quite sure about the list view and detail view aspects

Comment: `List View` will show all the instances in your respective `Model` (with/without pagination) while `Detail View` show the details of **One Instance** which is selected with an input_id

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Have fixed that part and added a few more details. What i am asking for, i guess, is something similar to a group-by query maybe ? Not sure though.  Just to be clear: I am trig to arrove at this: GET /blogs/1/author : to get a list of authors for the blog identified by id 1
Sample Output: {
                 id: 1,
                 blog_id:1,
                 authors:[1,2,3] #or authors:{1,2,3}
               }

Comment: I think your GET<POST and DELETE API's are not a standard one (in my opinion). you can write `.create()` inside your serializer to create new foreign key instances

Comment: I can help you more if you share your project